# Usage of "contributive" vs. "contributory"

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

Which of the two is more correct?

> *contributory capacity* or *contributive capacity*

(referred to the capacity of a province in ancient Mesopotamia to contribute to state demand for foodstuffs)

Answer (score 3):

If we're going to use NGram to make the case here, it would be wise to check specifically for usages with "capacity".
[image: .]

It's only my personal opinion, but I suspect that given *contributory* is a far more common word in general, it may be some usages here are erroneous for that very reason. I thought the correct form was **contributive capacity** before seeing the NGram, which seems to confirm my guess.

Comment: @drm65: I dithered, actually. I really wanted to just silently edit your chart, but I thought that might be a bit cheeky! Anyway, it's just another case in the long sorry saga of how we all get caught out by NGrams!

Comment: I am only the better for it!

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. So better contributive capacity rather than contributory.